# comparing characters causes a bus error

Tags: c++, char

I'm lost trying to figure out a runtime error.  I have a struct datatype, and an implementation of it in an array `items[]`.  In the struct, there is a `char name` defined.
I'm also reading a user input using cin into a `char` datatype.

```
i=0;
do {
printf("%c\n", items[i].name);
printf("%c\n", itemname);

//if ( items[i].name == itemname ) 
//found=true;
i++;
} while (i<numofitems || found);
```

if I uncomment the if statement, the `printf("%c\n", itemname);` seems to run thousands of times followed by `Bus error: 10`.  note the numofitems is current just 5.

Output from the way it is currently written:

```
A
C
B
C
C
C
D
C
E
C
```

Any idea why I can't simply compare if one char is equivalent to another?

Comment: "Bus Error", I believe means you are trying to use a memory address that isn't correctly aligned. You are probably going over some limit.

Comment: doh!  it had nothing to do with the code in the while loop.  +5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition should be `i<numofitems && !found`. Right now, if either is true, it keeps looping, and `found` becomes true on the third iteration.

I'd rewrite it as this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <numitems; ++i)
    std::cout << items[i].name << '\n';
    std::cout << itemname << '\n';

    if ( items[i].name == itemname ) 
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @chris mentions, your termination condition looks wrong.  If you set found to true, the loop will never terminate.

Comment: I apologize. That comment should have been an answer from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

When you set "found=true" you are making the loop run forever. Either change your loop test so you exit when found is set, eg

```
} while (i < numofitems && found == false );
```

or place a break statement after setting found, eg.

```
if ( items[i].name == itemname ) {
    found = true;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Also note that 10 characters are printed out. Each loop iteration prints twice, so the loop is executing fine, until i exceeds numofitems. Since 'found == true' at that point, the loop tries to iterate a sixth time, causing a bus error (more commonly known as a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault))